# Group a sets of recors obtaining IDS instead of objects

Tags: ruby

Just a brief question.

```
u.quizzes.group_by(&:section_id)
```

Return me

```
{1=>
  [#<Quiz id: 263, user_id: 2, exam_or_section: "section", section_id: 1>,
   #<Quiz id: 264, user_id: 2, exam_or_section: "section", section_id: 1>,
   #<Quiz id: 265, user_id: 2, exam_or_section: "section", section_id: 1>,
   #<Quiz id: 266, user_id: 2, exam_or_section: "section", section_id: 1>,
   #<Quiz id: 267, user_id: 2, exam_or_section: "section", section_id: 1>,
   #<Quiz id: 268, user_id: 2, exam_or_section: "section", section_id: 1>],
 2=>[#<Quiz id: 269, user_id: 2, exam_or_section: "section", section_id: 2>],
 3=>[#<Quiz id: 270, user_id: 2, exam_or_section: "section", section_id: 3>]}
```

Is there an easy way to get the ids array instead of objects?

```
{1=> [263,264,265, 266, 267, 268], 2=>[269], 3=> [270]}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
u.quizzes.select(:id, :section_id).group_by(&:section_id).each {|k, v| v.map!(&:id) }
```

The select is not strictly required but should be used, because the other fields arent used in any way and you would transfer useless data between the database and rails.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map`:

```
u.quizzes.group_by(&:section_id).map { |item| 
  [item.first, item.last.map { |q| q.id } ]
}.to_h
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it quite nicely.

```
u.quizzes.reduce({}) { |hash, quiz|
  hash[quiz.section_id] = Array(hash[quiz.section_id]) << quiz.id
  hash
}
```

And as p11y recommended `each_with_object`.

```
u.quizzes.each_with_object({}) { |quiz, hash|
  hash[quiz.section_id] = Array(hash[quiz.section_id]) << quiz.id
}
```

Comment: You can use each_with_object instead of reduce for building a hash iteratively. It will eliminate the need for returning the hash from the block explicitly. Note that the block parameters will have to be switched around.